# Python3 syntax in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I would like to use python3 syntax in PyCharm 2016.2 and have configured the interpreter to use python3.5. The code runs fine when I execute it but PyCharm complains about python3 syntax that isn't supported in python2.

How can I convince PyCharm that the python3 syntax is ok?

Comment: The author has already set the project interpreter correctly, you can do the same by following File -> Default Settings -> Project Interpreter, choose the version/env of python you are using.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Python -> Code compatibility inspection

Either disable it entirely or unselect Python 2.X

Comment: That was already disabled. It turns out I had to enable it and deselect python2.7. Thank you for the pointer!

Comment: This solution did not work for me. I ultimately fixed the problem by upgrading PyCharm.

Comment: this issue always comes back, I noticed when I open multiple projects (in new windows) they get confused. Looks like PyCharm does not isolate the projects well and the cache gets corrupt.