# This code only runs on python2.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, code-formatting

EDIT I just figured out what it was the map() function was what was causing it to not run properly i don't know why but a least it's working now thanks for all the help :)

I just updated my code to the pep8 code style guideline through pycharm but now it only runs on python2 when i run it when python3 i get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 28, in <module>
    soup.find_all("td", {"class": "location"})[1:],soup.find_all("td", {"class": "date-time"})[1:]):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

also the tracking number is not mine i just found it on the internet.
    import sys
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
s = requests.Session()
s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36 '
#if len(sys.argv) == 2:
#    trackingNumber = sys.argv[1]
#else:
#    print("Enter a tracking number to track a number.")
#    sys.exit()
r = s.get("https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction.action?tRef=fullpage&tLc=1&text28777=&tLabels=CX263292019US")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")



# Variable declaration.
current_status = soup.find(class_="detail-summary", )
some = soup.find_all("div", {"id": "tracking-results"})

for tag in some:
    divTags = tag.find_all("li")
    for tag in divTags:
        testrip = tag.encode("utf-8").strip()  # Remove all the white space off the text from bs4.
        if testrip == "The Postal Service could not locate the tracking information for your request." \
                      " Please verify your tracking number and try again later.":
            break

print(
    "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

print(current_status.get_text().strip())
for Status, Location, Time in map(None, soup.find_all("span", {"class": "info-text"}),
                                  soup.find_all("td", {"class": "location"})[1:],
                                  soup.find_all("td", {"class": "date-time"})[1:]):

    print(
        "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
    try:
        print(Status.get_text().strip())
        print(Location.get_text().strip())
        print(" ".join(Time.get_text().split()))
    except Exception:
        pass
print(
    "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
```

Comment: how exactly it fails on Python3?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `map(None, ...)`?

Comment: I am iterating over the information that bs4 gave me the none kept it would stop executing when one list ran out so but added an extra item to the lists so i fixed with the slice.

Answer (score 0):

Quick but a short term sustainable solution:

- add `from __future__ import print_function` (it's using Python3 syntax now)
- check if imports work under both Pythons? (in most cases they're coming with Python by default, but who knows what is your distribution)
- post the stacktrace if nothing of the above is working

More long term solution: [turn on Python 3 syntax checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588970/python3-syntax-in-pycharm) in Pycharm:

> Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Python -> Code compatibility inspection