# Wrong Python version in PyCharm's inspections

Tags: pycharm

Project Interpreter in PyCharm's settings for the project
"Python 3.6 C:\Anaconda\python.exe"

But in my code I get inspections like "Python version 3.5 does not support a 'F' prefix"

There is no Python3.5 on my system anywhere, I tried to resolve this doing the following:

- removed the interpreter in pycharm settings, then added it back
- uninstalled all other python versions, deleted their entries from windows registry etc
- updated anaconda / conda etc

nothing is working. And anyway why does PyCharm show that the python version is 3.6 when I select it as the project interpreter, but that it is 3.5 in inspections?

Comment: does File --> Invalidate Caches/Restart do anything?

Comment: @bvmcode no, it didn't help

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: @IonFreeman The OP accepted my answer below meaning that this is how the issue got solved.

Comment: @IonFreeman, yes, the Eskapp's answer solved it for me

Comment: I had to rebuild the project interpreter, which I did at the direction of JetBrains support.

Comment: @bvmcode It did work for me. The inspections setting was already correct.Odd

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Go to Settings->Editor->Inspections. There in Python->Code compatibility inspections, you should see that Python 3.5's box is ticked in.

This allows you to choose for which versions of Python your code will be inspected.

Comment: I started getting this error after I created a Jupyter notebook to test my flask API, and let PyCharm install Jupyter. I'm on macos, so I went to PyCharm/Preferences/Editor/Inspections/Python -- Code Compatibility was not checked. I checked it and it actually had 3.7 checked (as of this writing Python 3.7.0b4 is in pre-release.) I did invalidate caches and restart as well.

Comment: It seems that, unintuitively, 'code compatibility inspection' needs to be checked and the Python versions you don't care about need to be unchecked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588970/python3-syntax-in-pycharm#comment64566081_38589030

Comment: This issue can also crop up if you disable all Python inspections in Settings by un-ticking the Python language group and then re-enable them later.

Answer (score 7):

I totally agree with @Eskapp's answer, but here are a few additions that I had to do.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> **OR** <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> To open the Settings
2. Settings > Editor > Inspections > Python | Code compatibility inspection > Select the version(s) (In my case 3.7 and 3.8 and disselcting 2.7)
3. Settings > Project:  | Project Interpreter > Make sure correct version and interpreter is selected.
4. File > Invalidate Caches / Restart...
5. Done.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have Code Compatibility Inspection enabled. Please check the attached screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I often run into this issue due to symlinks. PyCharm apparently caches the interpreter version somewhere internally when you add a new Project interpreter. If that happens to be a symlink, and you later change the symlink to point to another path/interpreter, PyCharm will still think it's the old interpreter. In order to make it check the interpreter version again I need to go to that project interpreter and edit it - e.g. change the path to something else, and then back. It forces PyCharm to re-validate the interpreter and update cached version.