# Turn off 'Python version 3.5 does not support variable annotations' error message

Tags: python, types, pycharm, python-3.6, type-hinting

I just updated PyCharm to the latest version and I've been having trouble with this error message. Basically, I can't turn off the error message that says "Python version 3.5 does not support variable annotations."

My default and project interpreter is Python 3.6, and I don't even have Python 3.5 added in PyCharm, so any help with this would be much appreciated.

Some pictures:

[image: Picture of Pycharm IDE - Python version 3.5 does not support variable annotations]

[image: Picture of Pycharm IDE - Project Interpreter settings menu]

Edit: Updated with one more picture of the Project Interpreter settings:

[image]

Comment: What is parmetered in `File > Settings > Project : %your_project% > Project Interpreter` ?

Comment: Same thing - All it has is Python 3.6. I'll add another picture in case I'm looking in the wrong place

Comment: Try to search for `Python 3.5` in your `.idea` folder or the per-user settings directory...

Comment: No dice. Command "find .idea/  -iname '\*Python\*'" returned nothing. What do you mean by the per-user settings directory? Is that the .Pycharm2018.2 folder in my home folder? If so, that also returned nothing besides python.decorator files

Comment: Try to re-add interpreter

Comment: Ah, this is embarrassing...My Python 3 file in /usr/bin was pointing to Python 3.5 rather than 3.6, which was (/would obviously be) causing problems. Changed the interpreter to /usr/bin/python3.6 and the error is no more!

I thought I had checked the versions, but I guess not. Thank you  @user2235698! I saw this when re-adding the interpreter.

Comment: @user2235698 - If you'd like, create an answer explaining the solution and I'll accept it. Otherwise, I'll comment myself and mark this question closed.

Thank you everyone for helping out, I'm glad everything was resolved!

Comment: My only solution that worked was to upgrade from pycharm 2017 to pycharm 2018.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @user2235698, I fixed the issue by removing my project interpreter and re-adding it to Pycharm.

Ubuntu did an update which changed my Python 3 version from 3.6 to 3.5, but Pycharm didn't realize it was changed. Updating the interpreter directory from /usr/bin/python3 to /usr/bin/python3.6 fixed things.

Thanks again everyone! Marking this as solved.

Comment: There is an alternative - You need to turn off inspection/checks for the version you dont need as explained here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49821592/3518294