# Pycharm - 'Python version 3.5 does not support variable annotations' error message

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, typechecking

I do get the same error as described in [Pycharm - Turn off 'Python version 3.5 does not support variable annotations' error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51951256/pycharm-turn-off-python-version-3-5-does-not-support-variable-annotations-er)

I am using python 3.7, 3.5 has been uninstalled.
However re adding the interpreter does not fix the problem.
I also restarted pycharm, invalidated the caches, the issue persistently remains.

Comment: what OS are you using? Can you post a screenshot with the "Project Interpreter" combobox expanded?